# What tool can i use to synchronise files that doesn't require an installer?

Tags: backup, sync

I understand there are tons of utilities to synch files accross drives and folders, but i can't find any that do what i need. Specifically, i have:

- My home computer local storage
- My dropbox folder on my home computer, used primarily for backup
- My USB flash drive
- My files on the network in school

All the files are in 4 folders in each of these places called "School stuff".

Obviously any time i edit a file in any of these places i need to remember to manually copy the file over into the other 3 places - i want this to all synch up automatically at the soonest possible moment. The problem is, getting my USB flash drive to synch with the schools network folder when i insert it into a school computer.

*I don't have permissions to install anything on the school computers*, i do however have permissions to run an executable file.

In school, Microsoft Groove is installed which i tried to get working to do what i want, but it won't let me do anything from directly off a removable drive.

**Is there any way i can get everything to synch up despite the limitations?** I was thinking perhaps there is a program i could have as a standalone executable on my USB drive that will synchronise the folders when i run it. Of course any other solution is good too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the portable version of [**Toucan**](http://portableapps.com/de/apps/utilities/toucan).

Answer (score 1):

What you need is [portable `rsync`](http://en.kioskea.net/faq/sujet-2231-rsync-under-windows) that will work on Windows.
(compatibility with Linux/Unix would help someday).

- [cwRync](http://www.itefix.no/i2/) for Windows
- [DeltaCopy](http://www.aboutmyip.com/AboutMyXApp/DeltaCopy.jsp) for Windows (also [gHacks article](http://www.ghacks.net/2008/10/02/windows-backup-software-deltacopy/))
- And a [Python version](http://www.vdesmedt.com/~vds2212/rsync.html)

If you need to take rsync command line on USB flash drive to synchronize directories, you just install cwRync and get the following files: **rsync.exe**, **cygwin1.dll** and **cygz.dll**
This allows you to synchronize local directories (not in network).
<sup>check the example on that [`kioskea.net` link](http://en.kioskea.net/faq/sujet-2231-rsync-under-windows)</sup>

Comment: +1 because, despite i'm not going to use it, it looks like a viable solution as well as being good for any linux folk who are looking to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of maintaining 4 separate copies of your data, why not store it all in one place online using something like Google Docs or one of the online backup sites?

Comment: Because i'm extraordinarily paranoid about everything, especially school work. If i don't have 437 backups, i feel insecure. I forgot about google docs however, i'm definitely going to look into it as an alternative backup solution.